# Audio Player with Gapless Playback

Tags: audio, mediaplayer

I'm looking for an (preferably free) audio player on OS X that supports gapless playback.  It doesn't need to be fancy, I don't need any bells and whistles.  I just want gapless playback.  Unfortunately VLC doesn't support this, and though I've tried about half a dozen other players, none of them seem to implement this, or if they do I don't know how to enable it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'd also like to avoid iTunes if at all possible since I organize my music by folder and the ID3 tags aren't necessarily up-to-date... and I generally hate iTunes.

Comment: There are plans to [add gapless playback in VLC Player 4.0](https://www.neowin.net/news/vlc-40-to-drop-support-for-older-platforms-while-adding-new-ui-and-gapless-playback).

Answer (score 2):

[Vox](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24852/vox) | [Cog](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/18340/cog)

Both do gapless, Vox being the one I use.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple applications which can serve you these features. [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) for starters and also [Megaseg](http://www.megaseg.com/).

Comment: What's foobar2000?